# Window events for JFrames that are hidden/shown via setVisible?

Tags: java, swing, events

Which kind of listener do I have to add to a `JFrame` to detect when it is being hidden or shown via `setVisible`?

I tried using a `WindowListener` and the [`windowOpened`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html#windowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent)) and [`windowClosed`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html#windowClosed(java.awt.event.WindowEvent)) methods, but they only work for the *first time* that a window is opened (`windowOpened`) or, respectively, when the window is closed using the dispose method (`windowClosed`). That is not enough for me. I want to be notified every time the window is made visible and invisible on the screen using `setVisible`.

Is there a standard Swing way to achieve this, or do I need to make my own (by, say, overriding the `setVisible` method)?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try a `java.awt.event.ComponentListener`. You can add one using this code (where window is the name of the `JFrame`) :

```
window.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
   public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) {
      /* code run when component hidden*/
   }
   public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {
      /* code run when component shown */
   }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

1- Create a class that implements ComponentListener Interface, Like the following example:

```
    //---------------------
    import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ComponentListener;

    public class winlistenner implements ComponentListener {

        public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.print("Hided\r\n");

        }

        public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.print("Moved\r\n");

        }

        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.print("Resized\r\n");


        }

        public void componentShown(ComponentEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            System.out.print("Shown\r\n");

        }

}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

2- Now create a getter for your JFrame like this:

```
public class JMain {

    private JFrame frmNetworkshareMoon;
    private JTextField textField;
    private JTextField textField_1;
    private JTextField textField_2;

    public JFrame getFrmNetworkshareMoon() {
        return frmNetworkshareMoon;
    }


    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    JMain window = new JMain();
                    winlistenner listenner= new winlistenner();
                    window.getFrmNetworkshareMoon().addComponentListener(listenner);
                    window.frmNetworkshareMoon.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
//......
// the rest of your class code:
//...
}
```

3- being your main like the above example, you will set JFrame listener the listener you created, and then run the program, you will see messages coming from the listener:

```
Moved
Resized
Resized
Moved
Shown
Moved
Moved
```